# Not able to pass id from index in rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Project` model with one to many association with `Financial`, `Financial` model has one to many relationship with `PaymentMilestone` model. I want to add `new_payment_milestone_path` on the financial `index.html.erb`, but I am not able to pass `financial_id` on button click. 

Here is my code:

financial index.html.erb

```rb
    <% @financials.each do |financial| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= financial.responsibility %></td>
        <td><%= link_to " ", new_project_financial_payment_milestone_url(@financial, payment_milestone) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

financials_controller.rb

```rb
  def index
    @financials = @project.financials
  end
```

routes.rb

```rb
  resources :projects do
    resources :financials do
      resources :payment_milestones
        end
   end
```

Comment: Use `financial` instead of `@financial`,  remove `@` before financial as instance is not declared in controller.

`<%= link_to "Button", new_project_financial_payment_milestone_url(financial, payment_milestone) %></td>`

Comment: Also I don't from where `payment_milestone` coming from.

Comment: can I see your updated code?

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay as you said i added your code getting error - ```undefined local variable or method `payment_milestone' for #<#<Class:0x00007fbe6e5d8390>:0x00007fbe7b84aff8>```

Comment: As I said I don't know from where `payment_milestone` coming from. I just copy pasted your code and remove `@` only. you can remove that variable as well if it's not defined.

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay how can i pass that from controller index action?

Comment: You don't need to I think as while adding new `payment_milestone` we don't need `payment_milestone` object.

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay  i am asking how can i resolve this error - ```undefined local variable or method `payment_milestone'```. and add a button to ```new_payment_milestone_path. in existing nesting route as i mentioned.

Comment: you can pass from controller via index method `@payment_milestone =  {whatever query}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207398/discussion-between-hardik-upadhyay-and-rock).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't go nuts when resting:

> Rule of thumb: resources should never be nested more than 1 level
>   deep. A collection may need to be scoped by its parent, but a specific
>   member can always be accessed directly by an id, and shouldn’t need
>   scoping (unless the id is not unique, for some reason)
>   - [Jamis Buck](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources)

Making a pyramid out of your routes like you have makes things far more complex then they really should be. To unnest payment_milestones from projects  you need to change your routes to:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :financials
end

resources :financials, only: []
  resources :payment_milestones, shallow: true
end
```

This will create these routes:

```
     financial_payment_milestones GET    /financials/:financial_id/payment_milestones(.:format)                                   payment_milestones#index
                                  POST   /financials/:financial_id/payment_milestones(.:format)                                   payment_milestones#create
  new_financial_payment_milestone GET    /financials/:financial_id/payment_milestones/new(.:format)                               payment_milestones#new
           edit_payment_milestone GET    /payment_milestones/:id/edit(.:format)                                                   payment_milestones#edit
                payment_milestone GET    /payment_milestones/:id(.:format)                                                        payment_milestones#show
                                  PATCH  /payment_milestones/:id(.:format)                                                        payment_milestones#update
                                  PUT    /payment_milestones/:id(.:format)                                                        payment_milestones#update
                                  DELETE /payment_milestones/:id(.:format)                                                        payment_milestones#destroy
```

And you then can change your view to:

```
<% @financials.each do |financial| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= financial.responsibility %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "New milestone", new_financial_payment_milestone_path(financial) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

You want to use the local variable `financial` which is passed to the block and not the instance variable `@financial`. You should also always provide a link text for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

add this to button path-

```
new_project_financial_payment_milestone_url(@project, financial)
```